# ubuntu grep - how to concatenate parts of substring

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, pattern-matching, concatenation

I'm executing the following grep statement

```
grep 'duration: [[:digit:]]\{4,\}' file_name.log | grep 'execute' | grep -o 'duration: [[:digit:]]\{4,\}.*' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]\{4,\}.*' | sort -g -r
```

and it gives me the result like

> 26398.170 ms  execute: SELECT ... bla-bla ...
>
> 987687.234 ms  execute: SELECT ... bla-bla ...

I' m trying to figure out how to make it

> 26398 execute: SELECT ... bla-bla ...
>
> 987687 execute: SELECT ... bla-bla ...

something like `grep -o '[[:digit:]]\{4,\}' + 'execute.*'`

Comment: would suggest to add some sample lines from file_name.log itself to the question.. I feel like the task is better suited for sed/awk instead of grep... so need the original lines to work with

Comment: can you use sed after the last grep,like sed 's/\.[[:digit:]]\+ ms//g'

Comment: Nothing in your question or the answer(s) is specific to Ubuntu, by the way. Ubuntu uses GNU `grep` just like pretty much every other Linux platform, and lots of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` cannot reorder its input, it can only extract the match or the line which contained the match.

I'd suggest Awk for this, which also eliminates the long pipeline:

```
awk '/execute/ && match($0, /duration: [0-9]{4,}\.[0-9]* ms /) { 
   split (substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH), d);
   print int(d[2]), substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH) }' file_name.log |
sort -g -r
```

`match` finds the start and end of the substring in the input line which matches the regular expression, and populates the variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` so you can pull out the string which matched with `substr()`.  We split that string on whitespace and extract the second token, which is the numeric part of the match, and truncate that to just its integer part. `substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)` pulls out the rest of the string from the end of the match through to the end of the line.

If you are bad with Awk but good with regular expressions, you could use an even simpler `sed` script:

```
sed -n '/execute/!d;/.*duration: \([0-9]\{4,\}\)\.[0-9]* ms /!d;s//\1/p' file_name.log |
sort -g -r
```

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to clarify, awk and sed work with a group of files as file mask or with a single file? Actually I have                                                            awk '/execute/ && match($0, /duration: [0-9]{4,}\.[0-9]* ms /) {
   split (substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH), d);
   print int(d[2]), substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH) }' /logs/2018-01-*.log | sort -g -r > /var/log/JanuaryScript

Comment: Like most Unix commands with file name arguments, you can put as many files as you like, and if you don't put any, the command will read standard input. `cat`, `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, and many, many others all behave this way. (The one common aberration is `tr` which doesn't accept file name arguments at all.) If by "mask" you mean a wildcard, that gets expanded into a list of matching files by the shell before any command runs.